# How can I tell AnimationController's animation direction?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'd want to know if the controller is about to animate forward or is already animating forward.
Something like `controller.direction` would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

**There is**

`controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward || controller.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed`

But I wonder if there is something better

Answer (score 1):

You can use `controller.isAnimating` and `controller.status` to check if the controller is currently animating and in what direction.

Comment: If I'm checking `controller.status` I don't need to check `controller.isAnimating` because it is implied. `AnimationStatus.forward` would be enough in that case. I was hoping there is a another single check. I guess it is always possible to just add and extension method. Thank you for the answer.